# Question about the role of specific element in a circuit (H Bridge)

Tags: transistors, h-bridge, bipolar

I am currently studying different ways to design an H - Bridge and came across this circuit. I have a good idea how the bridge works except for the two transistors on the bottom that I have red circled. When I cut them off and simulate the circuit it seems that they do not affect the outcome at all. What is their use? Some sort of protection maybe?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are there to actively turn off the TIP120's, so that they turn off faster and in a more controlled manner.  Try simulating your circuit with higher PWM frequencies (I'd start at 20kHz) and see what happens.  Keep pushing it until you see shoot-through current (current spikes on the power line because a TIP125 and a TIP120 are both on at the same time) -- then put those transistors back in and see what happens.